# A VBA code that prompts the user how many rows he/she wants in an Excel file, then showing only such quantity of rows

Tags: excel, vba, rows

is there a way to ask the user how many rows he/she needs in an Excel file? And then with that information the worksheet will only show the required quantity of rows and hide every other cell, just to avoid the user to edit such cells.

As an example: It prompts how many rows I want, I type 3 rows and the excel worksheet will only have those 3 rows showing, the rest will be hidden automatically.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Excel is not an HTML/JavaScript which would only display the number of Rows that user provided. the VBA approach to hide rows would b a lot counter intuitive to any use cases.   Please read guidelines on how to ask questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok, thanks for giving me the HTML/JavaScript as an example, I understand it that way. And according to the guidelines, the only bad thing I see in my question is that I have not knowdledge in VBA, I just wanted to know if it was possible to do such thing in Excel, now I see I can not. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I never mentioned that it was impossible, I just said that it would be counter intuitive.
Try this and let me know if this works.

```
Public Sub HideRows()
    Dim RowsToKeep As Long
    RowsToKeep = CLng(InputBox("How many rows should I keep?") + 1)

    With ActiveSheet
        .Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        .Rows(RowsToKeep & ":" & .Rows.Count).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End With

End Sub
```

---

edit: Answer updated to reflect the response to comment

1. You must keep this code in the module.
2. Click Insert > Module.
3. Paste the code there.
4. In ThisWorkbook module, there are 2 dropdowns at the top.
5. Select first dropdown and select workbook.
6. 2nd dropdown will automatically,
7. select 'Open" and it will autogenerate a code for Workbook_open.
8. Just add 'Call HideRows' without quotes
   [image]

Comment: Hello Vilpur, I did not understand what you meant with "counter intuitive", I thoght you were saying I could not do such action in Excel, thanks a lot for your help. I am elaborating another question about this topic, in a more proper way as you said, I will give you the link as soon as possible, thanks for your time.

Comment: Oh okay as I had a bad review on my question, I can not keep asking for 2 days. I just wanted to prompt the question at the very moment an user opens the Excel file, here is a link to someone who asked something similar but when I puth the code in "ThisWorkBook" it does not work instantly when I open the excel file, I wanted to know what other modifications I would need to do such thing. Thanks

Comment: I have updated the answer to respond your question.

Comment: I tested it and it worked perfectly, thanks a lot Vipul, you were really helpful